# Is there a way to display orientdb interactive graph in a react webpage?

Tags: reactjs, orientdb, orientjs

I have an orientdb instance running and can access everything in Studio without any problem. My goal is to have a react webpage that has just the interactive graph embedded in it. Basically, I want to be able to look at the graph just like I would in Studio, but on my webpage. I know I could do this by doing a query and then creating an interactive graph through something like plotly, but I would rather just get the graph directly from the orientdb server. Is there support for this? I've been combing through the orientdb docs and have not found anything like this functionality, but I feel like it would be an obvious thing to have.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK there's nothing like that. OrientDB provides the REST api, then it's up to you build your interactive user interface embedded in your own application.

There is also ArcadeAnalytics https://github.com/ArcadeAnalytics/arcadeanalytics

It is a data visualization tool that works with OrientDB and other graph databases.
The frontend uses https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js to render the graph.
So, at least, you can take inspiration or extract the parts you need. 
I think that building a springboot application that uses the Orientdb connector (https://github.com/arcadeAnalytics/arcade-connectors/) should be easy.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I've been figuring, I appreciate the confirmation!